# Which string(in query) are empty?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So how to detect which string are empty in the query? I mean:
I have few WHERE clause in one query

```
$query = SELECT var FROM table WHERE var = '$y';
```

and how can I detect which "$y" has no result?

I know I can use `if($y)`, but how can I detect which was empty?

Comment: empty and no results are two different animals. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: cant you just look at the returned results from the query?

Comment: I mean no results sorry my fault, Im new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an array of your Y variables:

```
var $myYs =array($y1, $y2, ... $yn);
```

Then make a loop to count the query results of each of your Y. Then check if the count of that particular query was equal to 0, still inside the loop.

```
foreach ($myYs as $checkThsYnow){
    $query = SELECT COUNT(var) FROM table WHERE var = '$checkThsYnow';
    if ($query =0) {echo $checkThsYnow." is empty"}
}
```

Based on your comments additionally you need to check all combinations of your Ys.. as it is possible, that every Y brings back a result, but Y1 and Y2 AND together resulting the 0 results. Its a mathematical combination issue. Need to check all combinations..Loop in a loop in a loop..etc.

Comment: " I have few WHERE clause in one query"

Comment: oh, right, sorry... but I hope this solution works also by checking the Ys one by one. I assume that if you don't take the Ys separate then you will never see which brings you 0 result...